# Deserialize a json object for time series analysis

Tags: json

I would like to build a table showing the changes in stock prices over 1M, 3M, 6M, etc. The API call for a specific day in the past
returns the following json:

```
{
    "date": "2018-01-02",
    "data": {
        "AAPL": {
            "open": "170.16",
            "close": "172.26",
            "high": "172.30",
            "low": "169.26",
            "volume": "25555934"
        },
        "MSFT": {
            "open": "86.13",
            "close": "85.95",
            "high": "86.31",
            "low": "85.50",
            "volume": "22483797"
        }
    }
}
```

I have built a for loop in java that goes over the required dates using Calendar and make the API calls for those dates and a list of stock symbols. I am able to deserialize the json using the following code:

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
                    JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(result);
                    JsonElement jsonElement = jsonObject.get("data");
                    Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().entrySet();
                    entrySet.parallelStream().forEach(entry -> {
                        Stock stk = new Stock();
                        stk.setSymbol(entry.getKey());
                        stk.setClose(entry.getValue().getAsJsonObject().get("close").getAsFloat());
                        stk.setDate(date.getKey());
```

The problem is that using this code I can only save the data in my database that is unique by date. I wish to save it so that is unique by stock symbol. Presumably I need to collect the dates in a map object as a property to the POJO. Unfortunately, I have not been able to make it work. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Use: `LocalDate.parse( "2018-01-02" )`

Answer (score 0):

Create a flat table in your database, with columns for the date, the symbol (such as AAPL), and the five numbers. So seven columns all together.

This strategy assumes you have no additional data to store per date or per stock. (If you did have additional data per date or stock, you would need multiple tables, with parent tables for the date or the stock.)

Personally, I would slap on another column with a UUID generated as a primary key. I believe in always using [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). But not necessary strictly speaking, if your database supports a multi-column combination as a [natural key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_key). You could combine the date and the symbol together as a primary key to uniquely identify each row.

```sql
CREATE TABLE daily_high_low_ (
    date_of_closing_  DATE ,
    symbol_           VARCHAR( 4 ) ,
    open_             NUMERIC( 12 , 2 ) ,
    close_            NUMERIC( 12 , 2 ) ,
    high_             NUMERIC( 12 , 2 ) ,
    low_              NUMERIC( 12 , 2 ) ,
    volume_           INTEGER ,
    PRIMARY KEY ( date_of_closing_ , symbol_ )
)
```

I am purposely keeping this overly simplistic. In real life you would have to worry about stock [ticker symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ticker_symbol) not being unique across [stock exchanges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock_market). And I have hard-coded the numeric precision and scale for US dollars and cents amounts, which may not be appropriate for all markets. And we are ignoring the fact that date varies across time zones around the globe.

As you process your JSON, flatten the data to fit this flat table.

For retrieval, make a class to match this database table.

```
public class HighLow {
    public LocalDate dateOfClosing ;
    public String symbol ;
    public BigDecimal open, close, high, low ;
    public Integer volume ;
}
```

Load from database into a data structure that meets the needs of your data analysis. Perhaps hard-coded maps for each time period: months1, months3, months6, etc. Each maps the symbol to a list of `HighLow` objects.

To save memory, you share the same objects across the lists. For example, the list in the `months3` map has the same `HighLow` objects from the list in the `months1` map, plus two more months worth of `HighLow` objects.

```
Map< String , List< HighLow > > months1 = new TreeMap<>() ;
Map< String , List< HighLow > > months3 = new TreeMap<>() ;
Map< String , List< HighLow > > months6 = new TreeMap<>() ;
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I have alread flatten the data to my database. I only require the close so it looks like this: id, close, date, bucket, symbol. The bucket is for the time spans (e.g. 1M). The issue that I have is that I have not found a solution to use this structure in my controller. I need to inject the data to the view layer using Thymeleaf, but it complains that is not unique. I have been trying groupingBy using stream with no success. I guess I will have to keep trying. Thanks

Comment: @makasu Your Comment is quite different than your Question. Please put more effort into drafting a *very specific* question before posting.

Comment: Apologies, my comment was not very clear. Taking on board some of your comments in particular that for java.time classes, I have made some changes to my code. With these changes, I have managed to get something going, although the problem has not been fully resolved. I have decided to keep the flatten structure that I had already built, and work on loading the data into a structure that I can use for my controller. Many thanks for your help.